# How to Build a Browser Interface for a Numpy/Opencv Based Python Application

Tags: python, opencv

I have an application written in Python using numpy and OpenCV. Currently I am using OpenCV's GUI functionality; however, I'm finding it has various issues and behaves differently across platforms. I would like to build a browser interface. The application includes a live video feed and its state is updated about once every 1/15th of a second-- I would need the browser display to update at this rate. What is a good tool to accomplish this? I have built small apps in EmberJS but I think that getting it to communicate with Python is too much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to connect your app to a Python web framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) so that you can make a restful interface. You could then build a frontend app in [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) that queries the server for every update.